# How to serialize std::unordered_map with std::variant to binary file?

Tags: c++, binary, std, unordered-map, variant

Trying to find a way how to serialize
`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<bool, int, float, std::string>> m_Settings{};`

Is there any other way to serialize it other than going through each record in the map?

Comment: Use a tested serialization library, binary serialization is NOT trivial (you can't just load data in memory and cast that memory to an object for a lot of reasons).  This [github page](https://github.com/thekvs/cpp-serializers) reviews the performance of such libraries. protobuf isn't the fastest but well documented (and can help you with IPC too).